# gdialog does not allow entering or double clicking

Tags: 14.04, bash, dialog, zenity

The thing is, I have had pretty hard times with **gdialog** recently. Let's demonstrate the problem first with this bash code sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./Functionlib

temp1=$(mktemp -t tfile.XXXXXX)
while [ 1 ]
do
gdialog --title "ExampleProgram" --menu "Program Menu" 20 30 10 1 "FirstFunction" 2 "SecondFunction" 3 "ThirdFunction" 4 "Exit" 2> $temp1
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    break
fi
selection=$(cat $temp1)

case $selection in
1) FirstFunction
   ;;
2) SecondFunction
   ;;
3) ThirdFunction
   ;;
4) break
   ;;
*) gdialog --msgbox "Invalid selection" 10 30
esac
done
rm -f $temp1
```

So, basically everything works fine. But there is still a problem. When I'm trying to navigate between the options and I hit enter while on it, it triggers **Invalid selection** option. It doesn't matter if I navigate with pressing the right number or with arrow keys. Exactly the same happens when double clicking. So only way to choose an option seems to be clicking on it first to make it active, and then click 'OK'.

Initially I just thought there must be something about **gdialog** I don't know. But I used to create that kind of menus with **dialog** first. And everything mentioned above worked perfectly. I have tried to search for an answer everywhere, but not much information on **gdialog** is given. Still what I found out, it uses the same options than **dialog**.

So, is there still something that I'm not aware of? Yeah, it is pretty old I know, but could I make it work? Or should I use **zenity** instead?

Current system: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Kernel version: 4.2.0-35-generic

Comment: Tested your script , works without noticeable issues for me. `gdialog` is a wrapper around zenity by the way, so you are already using `zenity` , just with old syntax. Read what `gdialog --help` says. On a side note, it's probably redundant to have 4th option ( i mean, Exit ) because user already can exit using Cancel button. Also saves on code lines

Comment: @Serg Still I find it strange it doesn't work the way I want on my system. I guess the easiest option is to use new syntax instead of old though.